# New authorization changes affect FB JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

On the roadmap Facebook states that they will make changes to the way we get accesstokens. Will this affect the way we login with Javascript SDK?

> **New security restrictions for OAuth authorization codes**
>   We will only
>   allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and
>   will require that they be exchanged for an access token within 10
>   minutes of their creation. This is in line with the OAuth 2.0 Spec
>   which from the start has stated that "authorization codes MUST be
>   short lived and single use". For more information, check out our
>   Authentication documentation.

Link: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the roadmap Facebook states that they will make changes to the way we get accesstokens. Will this affect the way we login with Javascript SDK?

Of course it **does not**:

> “We will only allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once, […]”

Did you ever have to exchange an authorization code for a token yourself when using the JS SDK to log in?

No, since FB.login returns an access token directly.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your reply... however it was pretty rough :-)